# rqt_gui not working in ros melodic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i run rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui, i'm getting blank rqt gui like below:
[image: image description]

I'm using ros melodic, ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308141/rqt_gui-not-working-in-ros-melodic/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-11-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-11**:
"black" or "blank"? One is a colour, the other describes something that is empty / clean.

I don't see a black window in your screenshot.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-11-11**:
i mean to write blank.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-11**:
See whether #q251876 helps.

**Comment by [prashanthitata](https://answers.ros.org/users/51828/prashanthitata/) on 2020-02-17**:
Same problem. When I try opening controller manager crashes with the following error:

File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_controller_manager/controller_manager.py", line 386, in data
return self._icons[ctrl.state]
KeyError: 'initialized'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding a plugin.

---

Originally posted by [Tyrel](https://answers.ros.org/users/40650/tyrel/) with karma: 141 on 2019-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prashanthitata](https://answers.ros.org/users/51828/prashanthitata/) on 2020-02-17**:
Which plugin?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-05-05**:
image_view in visulization